# Facebook Share Dialog not opening when logged in

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a little bit stumped working with the Facebook api.

This is my code:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'myStory:object',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({object: "http://linkToMyStory.com"}),                
    app_id: 123456789            
    },         
    function(){}
);
```

If I'm not currently logged in to facebook, a popup opens asking for my password and then the share dialog is displayed, as expected. If I then later on try to post another story it also works.

#### But

If I'm already logged in when opening my site nothing is displayed. I see that data is being received from facebook but no popup is opened.

I tried to enclose the call to `FB.ui` in a call to `FB.getLoginStatus` like so:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.ui({ [...]});
    }
}
```

(saw that in an answer on this site)
but that gave me an uncatched type error `cannot read property domain of undefined`

Could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks  a lot!

Comment: A JS error in your code before that `FB.ui` call perhaps, that prevents further code execution – have you checked the error console …?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Nope, there is no error prior to the `FB.ui` call. There also is data coming back from facebook, just no window is opened...

Comment: Please note that you don't need to be logged-in to the app to use the share dialog. Try testing with different users (app test accounts ... etc) and see what happen